# Generating PDB files in QT release mode

Tags: qt, cmake, pdb-files, minidump

In a Windows QT application, I've successfully managed to call `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` and write out a minidump once the program crashes unexpectedly. However, as I've learnt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4850592/9655481), we need to instruct the compiler to create a "Program-Debug Data Base" (pdb file) with vital information for post-mortem code debugging, e.g. method and symbol names etc. Otherwise, the dump is kind of worthless when opened in WinDbg, as we don't get any meaningful stack traces and I need to see at which line my program crashed exactly. **So my goal here is to generate.pdb files alongside the release build** (to store them in a private archive for possible debugging scenarios when trying to debug a crash on the customer side).

I'm using a `CMakeLists.txt` file in *QT Creator* and don't get any .pdb files upon building. Based on [this forum post answer](https://forum.qt.io/post/457199) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9266033/9655481), I came up with this:

```
if (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    message("Configure with PDB debug information")
    set(QMAKE_CLFAGS_RELEASE "${QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE} /Zi")
    set(QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE "${QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE} /DEBUG /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF")
endif()
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, i.e. in my `out` folder under the respective release build folder, I do not find any .pdb files. The `if(...)` clause should not be the problem, as I see the message "Configure with PDB debug information" in the "General Messages" section of QT Creator when the project is built.

I've also tried to add

```
set(CMAKE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/pdb")
set(CMAKE_COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/pdb")
```

with no luck. I also had no luck with:

```
add_compile_options("/Zi")
add_link_options("/DEBUG")
add_link_options("/OPT:REF /OPT:ICF")
```

The values `QMAKE_CLFAGS_RELEASE` and `QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE` are correctly populated, so I don't know what I'm missing to get the .pdb files.

<sub>Note that I've also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35704181/9655481), however, I don't know how to get this to work with the classic CMakeLists.txt</sub>

---

**Edit**: Here is my current `CMakeLists.txt` file in Qt Creator.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(ProjectName VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

if (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    message("Configure with PDB debug information")
    set(CMAKE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/pdb")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL} /Zi /DEBUG")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL} /Zi /DEBUG")
endif()

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Network)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        ... (cpp and header files list of my project)
)

# https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmessagelogcontext.html
# By default, QMessageLogContext only captures in Debug mode,
# we change this so that this information is still available in other modes, e.g. Release mode
add_definitions("-DQT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT")

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(ProjectName
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    add_executable(ProjectName
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
endif()

target_link_libraries(ProjectName
    PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets
    PRIVATE Qt6::Network
)

set_target_properties(ProjectName PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

install(TARGETS ProjectName
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(ProjectName)
endif()
```

While building the project, I get this error (multiples times):

```
g++.exe: warning: /Zi: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++.exe: error: /Zi: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
g++.exe: warning: /DEBUG: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++.exe: error: /DEBUG: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
14:11:19: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake.exe" exited with code 1.
Error while building/deploying project ProjectName (kit: Desktop Qt 6.3.1 MinGW 64-bit)
When executing step "Build"
```

The *issue* pane in Qt contains these messages multiple times:

```
/Zi: linker input file unused because linking not done
error: /Zi: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
/DEBUG: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

The build commands passed to g++ by Qt are as follows:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\mingw1120_64\bin\g++.exe -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_WIN64 -IE:/project/path/out/minsizerelease -IE:/project/path/src -IE:/project/path/out/minsizerelease/ProjectName_autogen/include -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include/QtCore -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/mkspecs/win32-g++ -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include/QtWidgets -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include/QtGui -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/mingw_64/include/QtNetwork -Os -DNDEBUG /Zi /DEBUG -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/ProjectName.dir/qtutil/qslotthrower.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\ProjectName.dir\qtutil\qslotthrower.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/ProjectName.dir/qtutil/qslotthrower.cpp.obj -c E:/project/path/src/qtutil/qslotthrower.cpp
```

Comment: where did you place your `add_compile_options`? Did you place it _before_ the definition of the targets you want it to apply to? (because you need to)

Comment: Also, if you're trying to define you own configuration type, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11437692/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/75823363/11107541, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43746829/11107541

Comment: @user Yes, I placed it before the `qt_add_executable()`, `target_link_libraries()` and `install()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

The [post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/90561/generating-debug-symbols-pdb-for-release) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234337/qt-no-map-pdb-files-generated-for-windows-release-builds/9266033#9266033) you referred are all for **qmake**, not CMake. They would only work if you set them in a .pro file (not a CMakeLists.txt) and use qmake as your build system. If you're using CMake, variables like `QMAKE_CLFAGS_RELEASE` and `QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE` won't affect CMake at all.

*A bit off-topic: unless you have to deal with old projects that still use qmake, you should always stick to CMake since it's the de facto standard C++ build system and Qt/QtCreator now use CMake by default, too.*

To generate separate debug information in the **Release** build, you could add the following snippet to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Zi /DEBUG")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Zi /DEBUG")

# If it's the MinSizeRel build, then uncomment the following instead:
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL} /Zi /DEBUG")
# set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL} /Zi /DEBUG")

# Or apply the flags to all build types:
# set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /Zi /DEBUG")
# set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /Zi /DEBUG")

# Add your project's source files and build targets here...
```

That being said, the `add_compile_options`/`add_link_options` should also work (though the modern CMake way is using `target_compile_options`/`target_link_options`). I doubt you missed something in the CMakeLists.txt.

See:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html

---

Edit: I assumed you're using MSVC since you're developing Windows app, but this is not the case. [/Zi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format) and [/Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info) both are compiler flags for MSVC and minGW won't recognize them, this is where all the compiling errors stem from.

You should use [`-g`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) instead to generate debug info with MinGW. See [Can I make cmake always generate debugging symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540697/can-i-make-cmake-always-generate-debugging-symbols).

Note MinGW stores debug info in its own format rather than the Microsoft PDB. If you really want to generate PDB, I do recommend you switch to using MSVC for convenience (and remember to use a MSVC compiled Qt, too). See the discussion in [how to generate pdb files while building library using mingw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269350/how-to-generate-pdb-files-while-building-library-using-mingw)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that `QMAKE_CLFAGS` don't have any effect when using CMake ;) While CMake picks up the argument correctly now, I cannot build the project anymore and get a lot of "error /Zi linker input file not found: No such file or directory" and likewise for the `/DEBUG` flag and it's hard to find any answers for this problem online.